# Navigate pages mobile jquery

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am facing a problem while redirecting page from one .html file to another .html file.
here is my situation.

```
First.html
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="pageTest" data-role="page">
    <a id="lnkTest" onclick='$.mobile.changePage("Second.html#pageSecond");' data-ajax="false" data-         transition="slide">Sellers</a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

Second.html
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="pageFirst" data-role="page">
        </div>
    <div id="pageSecond" data-role="page">
        </div>
    <div id="pageThird" data-role="page">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I clicked on link in First.html file. It redirected to Second.html file with "PageFirst". But I want to redirect to Second.html file with “pageSecond”. 
How can I manage this link?
What will be the url to redirect there?
Can u please provide some solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to call the the other html file with multiple page.

```
<a id="lnkTest" href="page2.html#pageSecond" data-ajax="false">Seller</a>
```

Comment: i achived that as mentionaed my answer... can you help me with my other query mentiond in my ansewr... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

how about putting your all First.html and Second.html in a single page and call by there id. This work wee. i always do this without going to different files. Use just a single page it will be too easy too.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="pageTest" data-role="page">
        <a id="lnkTest" onclick='$.mobile.changePage("#pageSecond");' data-ajax="false" data-         transition="slide">Sellers</a>
</div>
    <div id="pageFirst" data-role="page">
    </div>
<div id="pageSecond" data-role="page">
    </div>
<div id="pageThird" data-role="page">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i achived that as mentionaed my answer... can you help me with my other query mentiond in my ansewr... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the onclick handler on your anchor tag is not the current way to perform a link.  Instead, try the following:

```
<a id="lnkTest" href="page2.html#pageSecond">Sellers</a>
```

The use of the "href" will be interpreted by jQuery mobile as a correct transition to the target HTML file and page.  In fact, the docs now say that [changePage](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/) has been deprecated.

This was tested with the following two files

**page1.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="pageTest" data-role="page">
        <a id="lnkTest" href="page2.html#pageSecond" data-ajax="false" data-transition="slide">Sellers</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

**page2.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="pageFirst" data-role="page">pageFirst</div>
    <div id="pageSecond" data-role="page">pageSecond</div>
    <div id="pageThird" data-role="page">pageThird</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Secondpage div won't be loaded, as jQM only parses first page div in each _external file_.

Comment: Omar is right... i want to load the any page on single html file.it will by defaukt load the first page.

Comment: @Omar Howdy Omar.  Thanks for the response but I tried it and it seemed to work just fine?

Comment: @daxeshS When I tested the code, I loaded page1 and clicked the link which then loaded page2 and showed the "pageSecond" Mobile page.  Am I misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Kolban I am trying to achive is redirection from one html file to second html file which contains multiple page(Data-role="page")..by default it selects the first(Data-role="page").... but What if i want to navigate to the second(Data-role="page") or third page(Data-role="page")... but i achived that mentionaed my answer below... can you help me with my other query mentiond below in my ansewr... thank you.